# Join documents in array mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have collections of characters here like this.

```
characters collection
{ 
    _id: objectId(1), //this is just an example id
    name: 'harry'
},
{
    _id: objectId(2),
    name: 'ron'
},
{
    _id: objectId(3),
    name: 'dumbledor'
},
{
   _id: objectId(4),
   name: 'Super Man'
}
```

then i have another one

```
movie collection
{
  _id: objectId(1),
  heroes_id: [
      _id: objectId(1),
      _id: objectId(2),
      _id: objectId(3)
  ],
  movie: 'Harry Potter'

}
```

I wanted it to join them like this

```
{
      _id: objectId(1),
      heroes_id: [
          _id: objectId(1),
          _id: objectId(2),
          _id: objectId(3)
      ],
      movie: 'Harry Potter',
      cast: [
        {    
          { 
               _id: objectId(1), //this is just an example id
               name: 'harry'
           },
           {
              _id: objectId(2),
             name: 'ron'
           },
           {
             _id: objectId(3),
              name: 'dumbledor'
            },
        }
      ]

    }
```

i have a piece of code with `mongodb` functions

```
                  movie.aggregate([
                  {
                      $unwind: "$heroes_id"
                  },
                  {
                      $lookup: {
                          from: "characters",
                          localField: "heroes_id",
                          foreignField: "_id",
                          as: "cast"
                      }
                  },
                  {
                      $match: { "cast": { $ne: [] } }
                  }
              ]).exec(function(err, results) {
                      if(err) res.status(500).send(err);

                      res.status(200).send(results);
              });
```

so i just wanted to join the two collections. it work but it get only one. please help me out thanks.

Comment: What is your MongoDB server version and is `heroes_id` an array of just ObjectIds or an array of documents i.e. `[ObjectId(1), ObjectId(2), ObjectId(3) ]` vs `[ { _id: objectId(1) }, { _id: objectId(2) },
{ _id: objectId(3) } ]` ?

Comment: this is just an example `objectId`

Comment: I understand it's just an example, but still unclear what `heroes_id` array is from your example. Also, what is your MongoDB server version?